# Knockout unexpected identifier "."

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm creating a new app with knockout and i'm having a very weird error. I use knockout for a while and never had this error before.

Whenever I try to use the "$root." pseudoselector, knockout returns me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: click: .createAlarm
Message: Unexpected token .
```

In this case, the binding was:

```
<button class='btn' data-bind='click: $root.createAlarm'>New alarm</button>
```

The same thing happened when I tried to reference a viewmodel function inside a foreach binding.

Here's my code:

```
function ViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                // data
                // set initial time for alarm
                self.alarmHour = ko.observable(moment().hours());
                self.alarmMinute = ko.observable(moment().minutes());
                self.alarmSecond = ko.observable(moment().seconds());
                self.chosenAlarmTrack = ko.observable();
                self.alarms = ko.observableArray();

                // methods

                self.createAlarm = function() {
                    var timeNow = moment()
                    var alarmTime = getNewTime(self.alarmHour(), self.alarmMinute(), self.alarmSecond());
                    var alarmTime = moment(alarmTime)

                    if (timeNow.isAfter(alarmTime)) {
                        alarmTime.add(1, "day");
                    }

                    self.alarms.push(new Alarm(alarmTime, self.chosenAlarmTrack()))
                }


            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var vm = new ViewModel();
                ko.applyBindings(vm);
            })
```

Comment: Which kind of webserver/hosting provider/reverse proxy are you using? From the error message it seems that something removed the `$root` text from your HTML...

Comment: I'm using localhost. I thought it could be some problem with encoding, but doesn't seem to be

Comment: Indeed, in the HTML, the $root is not there. I'm using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post but I had the same issue and found the solution.

Since the PHP templating treats `$` as PHP variable all you need to do is substitute the `$` for its html code `&#36;` equivalent.

So instead of using

```
$parent
$root
```

use

```
&#36;parent
&#36;root
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because somewhere in your html you are reassigning the value of the context object for $root.  Check your HTML for a binding using a single equal instead of a double or triple equals -

```
<div data-bind="visible: $root=''"></div>
```

If that isn't the case can you post your HTML?

Comment: isn't this the case. I tried with "$parent" and the problem is the same. And this click binding is the second binding in my code. (the first is a "data-bind="visible: true"".

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - I'm using a php templating system, and when it finds a "$" character it assumes that is a PHP variable.